# FFMPEG to periscope or twitter

Tags: twitter, ffmpeg, video-streaming, live, periscope

In twitter studio to stream they specify

RTMP URL rtmp://va.pscp.tv:80/x

RTMPS URL rtmps://va.pscp.tv:443/x

but when I do

```
ffmpeg -re -i file.webm -c:v libx264 -preset ultrafast -vf "scale=-2:1080" -g 60 -pix_fmt yuv420p -c:a aac -b:a 128k -ac 2 -r 30 -vb 900k -minrate 900k -maxrate 900k -bufsize 900k -ar 44100 rtmps://va.pscp.tv:443/x/
```

I get this error

```
Unable to find a suitable output format for rtmps://va.pscp.tv:443/x/key: Invalid argument
```

I tried with and without the x but nothing goes, still same error

how to fix this

Answer (score 2):

Turns out it was only missing -f flv

```
ffmpeg -re -i str_CAM_HGgs_con_XZQOm4Zem0.webm -c:v libx264 -preset ultrafast -vf "scale=-2:1080" -g 60 -pix_fmt yuv420p -c:a aac -b:a 128k -ac 2 -r 30 -vb 900k -minrate 900k -maxrate 900k -bufsize 900k -ar 44100 -f flv rtmps://va.pscp.tv:443/x/{KEY}
```